# Problems in getting RPM message from OBD2

Tags: c, uart, obd-ii

I am new in OBD2 programming. I have my device connected through serial port to OBD2. I try request RPM or Speed messages and getting "SEARCHING..." or "NO CONNECT" messages instead of a RPM/Speed values. I tried to send "ATZ" and even "ATSP00" commands before the RPM/Speed request, but it still the same issue.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have a faulty OBD2 adapter or you don't have the ignition on or your car speaks a l1/l2 protocol that your adapter does not support.

Make sure to issue `ATSP0\r\n` before `0100\r\n`. If you still don't get any answer and ignition and/or engine is on, then check with another OBD2 adapter.